# How to use active character properly?

Tags: symbols, characters

Suppose I use `'` as active character to insert another symbol:

```
{\tt A'C B}

\def\adef#1{\catcode`#1=13 \begingroup \lccode`\~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}}
\let\oldtt\tt\def\tt{\adef'{\char"0D}\oldtt}

{\tt A'C B}

{\tt A'c B}
\bye
```

Log file contains this:

```
Missing character: There is no ^^dc in font cmtt10!
```

Why in the second case the result is not `A'C B`, although the third case works as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to not having a space in the definition of the active `'`:

```
\adef'{\char"0D}
```

should be

```
\adef'{\char"0D }
```

so TeX will know where the constant terminates (and the space will be gobbled by TeX rule).

In the first case, TeX is presented with

```
'C
```

that becomes

```
\char"0DC
```

and TeX duly looks for character number `"DC` (which of course doesn't exist in a seven bit font).

In the second case the input stream is

```
\char"0Dc
```

and, since `c` is not legal in an hexadecimal number, according to the syntax rules, the found number is `"0D` that's what is wanted.

*Always* leave a space after a required constant.

Comment: May `\relax` be used in such cases instead of space?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Using `\relax` may be bad in cases where full expandability is needed. In the case of `\char`, there's no problem.