# Why to store a number via chardef?

Tags: plain-tex

For example, in plain.tex and in hyrules.tex (package hyplain) we find such code:

```
\chardef\active=13 \catcode`\~=\active
```

```
\chardef\myh@us@catcode=\the\catcode`\_
...
\catcode`\_=\myh@us@catcode
```

Are there any other ways to store a number and why this way is preferable to others?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This trick spares on tokens and avoids problems with termination of constants.

For instance, LaTeX has `\chardef\@ne=1` and `\mathchardef\@M=10000`; memory is less cluttered if `\penalty\@M` is stored instead of

```
\def\nobreak{\penalty10000 }
```

(note the extra space, see [How to use active character properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243572/how-to-use-active-character-properly) for an example of where this space is important).

Note also that `\penalty\@M` is already finished and TeX will not look for a space token to remove, because `\@M` is unexpandable.

In your case, it would be the same doing

```
\edef\myh@us@catcode{\the\catcode`\_ }
...
\catcode`\_=\myh@us@catcode
```

Also `\def\active{13 }` would be a substitute of `\chardef\active=13`, but using the latter avoids expansion problems.

However, the first line of the code you show should better be

```
\chardef\myh@us@catcode=\catcode`\_
```

because the `\the` serves no purpose: when TeX is looking for a `<number>`, primitives such as `\catcode`, `\lccode` and similar are allowed and will return the value, without the extra step of converting it into its decimal representation.

<sub>And, yes: I'm the author of `hyplain`. :-) A slip. `;-)`</sub>

Answer (score 11):

It is traditional to store such numbers as `\chardef` (or `\mathchardef` to get a larger range)  eg plain tex has

```
\chardef\@ne=1
\chardef\tw@=2
\chardef\thr@@=3
\chardef\sixt@@n=16
\chardef\@cclv=255
\mathchardef\@cclvi=256
\mathchardef\@m=1000
\mathchardef\@M=10000
\mathchardef\@MM=20000
```

This stores the number as a single token so it is more efficient in space and time than say

```
\def\@cclv{255 }
```

an alternative would be a count register but in classic TeX there are only 256 registers of each type so they are a scarce resource.